# AngularJS: read only input with ng-readonly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird problem with passing a boolean to a text. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anvarik/3cnV9/3/)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>First Name:
    <input ng-model="first" ng-readonly="true"/>
    </p>
    <p>Last Name:
        <input ng-model="second" ng-readonly="{{truefalse}}"/>
    </p>
</div>

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.first = "Angular";
    $scope.second = "JS";
    $scope.truefalse = "true";
}
```

Can someone explain me why second field is still modifiable?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to pass your scope in ng-readonly without Braces.
And $scope.truefalse shouldn't be a string, so you don't need quotes.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>First Name:
    <input ng-model="first" ng-readonly="true"/>
    </p>
    <p>Last Name:
        <input ng-model="second" ng-readonly="truefalse"/>
    </p>
</div>

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.first = "Angular";
    $scope.second = "JS";
    $scope.truefalse = true;
}
```

Comment: I have in `input type="text" ng-model="myObject.value"` field and when I set the `ng-readonly="true"` directive on it the model value does not appear in the text field any more... any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

when ever we are using model inside element like as attribute no need use curly braces, but whatever code not working in your case it's working fine for me below is working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="convertApp">
<head>       
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>First Name:
            <input ng-model="first" ng-readonly="true"/>
        </p>
        <p>Last Name:
            <input ng-model="second" ng-readonly="{{truefalse}}"/>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                        var app = angular.module('convertApp', []);
                        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                            $scope.first = "Angular";
                            $scope.second = "JS";
                            $scope.truefalse = "true";
                        });
    </script>   
</body>
```